# Test fail in IFTTT with "returns at least three items"

Tags: service, triggers, action, iot, ifttt

I'm creating my own service and in the endpoint test fails here and this error is shown:
"returns at least three items"

This error comes from the trigger part.

Can somebody share a sample value of output with three items in it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFTTT Expects you to send at least 3 result items, to skip just clone the same object twice with different ids.

From the FAQ section;

> **My service fails the returns at least three items endpoint test. Why does IFTTT require three items?** We require three items during the
> testing phase to make sure your API behaves like a timeline of events,
> not a state engine.
>
> This requirement might seem strange when you think of your integration
> with IFTTT as something that is entirely realtime in nature, like “IF
> Button Pressed, THEN Turn On Lights”— what good would come from
> anything but the current state of the button?
>
> But what about the Applet “IF Button Pressed, THEN Log to
> Spreadsheet”? In this case it would be important to store and return
> multiple event items because there is no guarantee that we’ll call
> your API (even with the Realtime API) at the moment the event occurs.
>
> By keeping and returning a list of events, IFTTT users are more
> assured they won’t miss a thing.